# Is it possible to create your own security updates on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: updates

**My main Question is:
Is it possible to create your own security packages?**

*[ **NOTE:** I enjoy teaching myself new skills for many different things. So please give me an answer in a 4th grade reading level. What I mean is that I won't have a clue what you're trying to tell me if the words are way to hard for me to understand. I have a hard time using a dictionary and understanding vocabulary words.]*

-Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual definition of a security upgrade (as used by unattended-upgrades, the package which does automated security upgrades) is this

```
"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
```

(from /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades)

So, to create a security upgrade, you need to [set up your own repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/89698/3813), and add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` on every machine which you want to receive the upgrade:

```
deb http://yourserver.example.com/ubuntu precise-security main
```

(precise is the distro codename for 12.04, replace `yourserver.example.com` with the hostname of your repository server and `main` with the name of your repository)

Of course if you want to create a security upgrade for every Ubuntu user in the world, you need to become a package maintainer or a [Ubuntu Developer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment)

Answer (score 0):

If you find vulnerability(bug in Ubuntu) and make a patch for it(repair it), they are like writing software. But you should submit them to the Ubuntu team, with the vulnerability. I hope that you understand me.

Comment: Also I forget to mention, to write patchs you need to be familiar with C. To find vulnerabilities, you need to be familiar with C, a little bit of assembly will be helpful, you will also need to be familiar with memory management and the different type of exploits. For C I will recommend watching the lectures made by MIT open course wave, for assembly and other things look for open security training in google. Wish you good luck!